# Acionar eventos remotamente

Tags: c#, eventos

Qual a melhor forma acionar/receber um evento remotamente no `C#`?

**Exemplo:**

Ao clicar em um botão no PC1, executar determinada tarefa nos outros PC's que possuem o app.

Pensei em 3 soluções:

1. Socket
2. Realizar consultas ao banco de dados em intervalos de 5s
3. Realizar consultas http que retorne algum `json` em intervalos de 5s

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. Você quer saber qual a melhor opção, dentre as três?

Comment: Sim, ou alguma outra sugestão. @RenilsonAndrade

Comment: Creio que as soluções 2 e 3 são as mais fáceis de fazer (ao menos no meu ponto de vista)

Comment: O performático seria algo assim: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973857.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vai depender da arquitetura que você utilizou para construir o software. Se você possui uma aplicação servidora, que forneça conexão com os clientes via socks ou WCF, então este é o caminho. Utilize a mesma arquitetura da camada para enviar as informações (socks, wpf, remoting ou outros)

Agora, caso suas aplicações clientes se conectam com o banco de dados diretamente, a solução pode ser criar uma tabela e pegar a atualização de tanto em tanto tempo. Você poderia deixar uma thread rodando isolada no cliente, verificando alterações. Isso evitaria a construção de uma aplicação servidora exclusiva para este fim

O caso do json só aconselharia para aplicações web. Se sua aplicação for web de uma olhada nesse recurso do html5.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp